# Neo4j Performance Issue while creating relationship on existing nodes?

Tags: neo4j

Indexes for Products:

1. ON: Products(SaleID)
2. ON: Products(CountryID)
3. ON: Products(ProductID)
4. ON: Products(ID)
5. Few more Properties...

Indexes for Orders:

1. ON: Orders(SaleID)
2. ON: Orders(CountryID)
3. ON: Orders(ProductID)
4. ON: Orders(ID)
5. Few more Properties...

Product has 50K nodes

Orders has 500K nodes

When I create relation on the above scenarios on the existing nodes.
 It takes 15 mins in community version 3.1.

Query:

```
MATCH(prod:Products) 
WHERE prod.ID = 999 
WITH prod 
MATCH (ord:Orders) 
WHERE ord.ID = prod.ID and ord.SaleID=prod.SaleID and ord.CountryID  = prod.CountryID and ord.ProductID = prod.ProductID 
CREATE (prod)-[prod_ord]->(ord)
```

current conig:

RAM - 64g
heap max = min = 32
Page swap = default/auto

DB hit -> 500 million hits

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIGQd.png)

Q1. Its not considering the Indexes, How do I force it to considering indexing via  the following indexes?

Using Index ON prod:Product(SaleID)

Using Index ON prod:Product(ProductID)

Using Index ON prod:Product(CountryID)

Using Index ON prod:Product(ID)

Q2. Why does it take so much time? Any configuration needs to be done?
Or data model is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses `Products` label, but your index is on `Product`.

Also extract the product id as parameter and use it in the second match. It should then use the `Orders(ID)` index:

```
MATCH (prod:Products) 
WHERE prod.ID = {prodId} 
WITH prod 
MATCH (ord:Orders) 
WHERE ord.ID = {prodId} and ord.SaleID=prod.SaleID and ord.CountryID  = prod.CountryID and ord.ProductID = prod.ProductID 
CREATE (prod)-[prod_ord]->(ord)
```

You can set the parameter in the browser by

```
:param prodId : 999
```

The other indexes are probably not very useful, because usually doing a lookup on one property and then filter the results is faster than using multiple lookups and doing some kind of join. If some of the properties is more unique use that instead.

Comment: 1. The index is on Products only...There was typo error here.  I have corrected it now.                                                                                        2. The relationship is created via desktop client application. Hence, the prodID is dynamically assigned. The relationship is created every time triggered from client. Can you help me with the performance issue here?

Comment: Can we force the query to "Use Index" ?

Comment: @neoman1 you could try to swap the match clauses, this could reduce the number of rows that need to be filtered.